# How to do button keep pressed and release that button after click another button?

Tags: android, button

How can I make button keep pressed and release that button after click another button?

**Example:**

I have two buttons: `A` and `B`

- When button `A` is clicked, it should stay pressed.
- When button `B` is clicked, button `A` should be released.

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final Button bOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_one);
final Button bTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_two);
bOne.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        view.setPressed(true);
        bTwo.setPressed(false);
        return true;
    }
});
bTwo.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        view.setPressed(true);
        bOne.setPressed(false);
        return true;
    }
});
```